# Drawing longer arrows in TikZ

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

I have the following diagram:

```
\begin{tikzcd}[font=\large]

A \rightarrow & B  & C \leftarrow & D\\

E \arrow[hookrightarrow]{u} \rightarrow   & F  \arrow{ru} & G \leftarrow \arrow{ru}

\end{tikzcd}
```

Is there a way of "drawing" a longer arrow in the 2nd row such that F is below C and G is below D?

Comment: Could you please give us a little drawing of what you want to have? I do not understand. Have you read the manual for `tikz-cd`? You should not use `\rightarrow\leftarrow` here, but `\arrow{r}` or `\arrow{rr}` or as long as you please. If you want to have `F` under `C`, you will have to add more `&`-signs in order to leave cells empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want this? Your question is not very clear.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[font=\large] 
    A \arrow{r} & B  & C \arrow{l} & D\\    
    E \arrow[hook]{u} \arrow{rr} & & F  \arrow{u} & G \arrow{l} \arrow{u}   
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes. Exactly this. Sorry i had trouble writing here in TeX